# Filtering Arc values in c#

Tags: c#, filter, dxf

I'm having trouble filtering an Arc value.

When I draw a bitmap (dxf file into bmp) there is always extra arcs with the same values, no matter the file im working with.
[image: The extra arc]

Library : netDxf

```
 else if (entity is Arc arc)
 {
     
     double sweepAngle = arc.EndAngle - arc.StartAngle;
     arc.EndAngle = sweepAngle;
                 
     
     entityInfo = $"Processing Arc: Start Angle=({arc.StartAngle}), End Angle=({arc.EndAngle}), Radius={arc.Radius}, Sweep Angle =({sweepAngle})";

     graphics.DrawArc(Pens.Black, (float)(arc.Center.X - arc.Radius), (float)(arc.Center.Y - arc.Radius),

     (float)(2 * arc.Radius), (float)(2 * arc.Radius), (float)arc.StartAngle, (float)arc.EndAngle); 
 
                         
 }
```

I'll remove the `entityInfo` afterwards, I used it just to get the `arc.StartAngle` value of the extra arcs.

I already tried this `if (arc.StartAngle == 270.565033310363) return ;`, expecting it to enter the if but it didn't.

Comment: `arc.StartAngle == 270.565033310363` will allmost never return true.  loating-point-arithmetic doesn't work well will what you consider to be equal. You may use a very small *range* of values, e.g. check for `arc.StartAngle >= 270.565033310362 && arc.StartAngle <= 270.565033310364` (or `Math.Abs(arc.StartAngle - 270.565033310363) < 0.000001`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating-point numbers and equality don't fit well, at least not in that way you expect it to. The point here is, that not every decimal number (e.g. 270.565033310363) can accurately be represented as floating-point number. You will  allmost allways get an *approximation* for that number, e.g 270.565033310364.

So in order to compare floating-point-numbers (e.g. numbers with type `double`), you need to handle a very small *range* within that you consider two numbers to be equal, often called *epsilon*.

So you may use this instead:

```
var epsilon = 0.000001;
if (Math.Abs(arc.StartAngle - 270.565033310363) < epsilon)
    return;
```